# Understanding resonance detectors

Tags: rf, detector

I'm exploring an old device that detects RF frequency. It has a generator of bipolar spike pulses +-1V interleaved by 0V sections, diodes and antennae (L1).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGAnLW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have some basic issues understanding the principle of this simple circuit. I'm therefore seeking an advice or correction to my reasoning.

I think by design it was not set to the resonating frequency that matches the RF signal of 20khz. All values are actual, but I'm a little bit unsure of L1, it was measured with an ad-hoc arduino circuit.

1. Looks like positive V1 pulse is getting to the ground via diodes.
2. The negative pulse charges capacitor C1.
3. The resistor is here to make some little current flow just to catch up the RF.
4. C1 starts discharging when V1 rises from -1V to 0, this should make the negative spike smoother.
5. The C2-L1 catches some part of the RF wave, inducing some potential (positive or negative).

I'm having difficulties to understand how C2-L1 affects the current in the circuit.

The circuit also drives a transistor Q1 (always open) that controls the LED. The transmitter is another device, its frequency can be adjusted and when it matches the V1 frequency, the LED goes almost off.

Comment: Your title/tags asks about detectors and your question is NOT about detectors but emitters.

Comment: It's actually a heterodine detector, it drives a transistor that controls the brightness of a LED (not shown here). When frequency of an emitter (another device) matches the V1 generator, the LED goes almost off.

Comment: So, if there's this something that you want explaining because you don't understand it, don't make simplifications to that thing because you'll just confuse people like me. Show the fuller picture please.

Comment: Where is the antenna connected in the circuit? Is it the coil?

Comment: The antenna is sealed, it has 2 wires and a shielding wire. One of the wires is connected to the shield at the side of the device, the shield is also connected to ground. The other wire is connected between diodes.  I think the antenna is a simple coil, I measured its inductance as 100uH and its DC resistance was 35 ohm. The length of the cable is 15 cm, at the end of the cable the coil is supposingly located, at least it has a thicker part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess: It's a [lock-in amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-in_amplifier). It is used to find weak signals buried in noise. The oscillator signal and the input-signal are multiplied together, and only input-signals that have the exact frequency of the oscillator (or its odd harmonics as it's a square) will result in detection (=Charging of C2).

This picture from wikipedia shows how it may have been used:

[image: Use of fa lock-in ampllifier]